# Retrieving post titles and links of a specific blog

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

i want to make a personalized blog archive to be displayed in a widget. So is there a way to get all the post titles and links for a particular blog? Preferable with ascending date.

Even better would be to make it possible to group posts some way. Say i have a topic that is divided into 3 posts. The viewer sees the topic in the side bar and when he clicks it the other parts are visible. This makes browsing a lot easier. Right now i have this hierarchical list that comes standard with blogger. It is a mess, it would be much better if i could group my blogs like described.

I do not want to invent the wheel, but my searches did not yield any results on existing widgets or how to develop something like this.

Example:
I blog about gadgets so the blogs for phones i label or catagorize as "phones". A list like this should be shown.

```
-Phones(4) <-click to expand
  -Iphone 2
  -Iphone 3
  -Samsung galaxy S (part 1)
  -Samsung galaxy S (Part 2)
```

Right now if i use labels all the content of the label is being shown. I just want individual blogs to show up.

Comment: Found some more reading material on the subject. Help or a link the a working widget is still appreciated though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess i have to settle with my own javascript plugin and edit it each time i post something new.